# Entity Framework Run Query without binding to class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

With EF you usually match a class to a table and you can run manual queries and stored procedures but you still have to include a class that it will match up with.  Is it possible to use the DbContext to run a custom sql query and use the return value(s) somehow without matching it to a class?

I have a need to run custom sql statements entered by users where I won't know what columns are returned so I can't simply match it to a class like normal and I want to avoid using DataTables, DataRows etc if I can as I would use this if its not possible and simply loop through the columns in each DataRow.

Comment: probably you need to expand the description with sample input, like is it comma separated string, or list of string, or something else? what the desired return types; anonymous type, list, entity type, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run any query and have it return an anonymous type

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738512%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know why someone marked it down as it answered my question exactly, thank you.

Comment: On the surface I would have said that this doesn't answer the question due to the fact that anonymous types cannot be defined at runtime. But as it's been marked as the correct answer I assume that the question was a little vague. "I have a need to run custom sql statements entered by users" sounds like the statements are being entered at runtime. If the selected columns of the sql can vary runtime then this solution will not work.

Comment: Only a link is not a sufficient answer